# How to join 2 Table python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

i would ask How can you  join 2 tables using sqlite3 on python pycharm ,i tried diffrent things , but this one seems to be  correct but idk why it's not working (Knowing that i already inserted those values) , thanks

```
emp1=Employee('Bekri','Toufik')
emp2=Employee('Halim','Ryad')
P1 = Project('El achour','Alger')
P2 = Project('Douaouda','Tipaza')
#join tables
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM Employee 
                    INNER JOIN Project  Where PName = El achour
                    ON PEmployee = EmpId
                    Where EmpName = 'Halim' """)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON` is part of the `JOIN` clause, you can't put it after `WHERE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Project ON PEmployee = EmpId
WHERE Pname = 'El achour' AND Empname = 'Halim'
```